# Selecting data from different rows

Tags: postgresql

I want select the opening balance of the first month and the closing balance of the last month in PostgreSQl then now i the sum of income as total income and sum of expenditure as total expenditure on the same row... Here is my data below

```
ID OPENING_BAL INCOME EXPENDITURE CLOSING_BAL COUNCIL_NAME DATE_COMPILED
21   5000.00   1000.00  2000.00   6000.00     BAKONE       2017-04-28
22   6000.00   1000.00  4000.00   9000.00     BAKONE       2017-05-31
23   9000.00   1500.00  2000.00   9500.00     BAKONE       2017-06-30
```

Comment: Please add the desired result

Comment: OPENING_BAL  TOT_INCOME TOT_EXPENDITURE CLOSING_BAL 
  5000.00              8000.00            3500.00                      9500.00

Comment: I konw, paste the desired result according to your sample data.

Comment: You want this all to come back in one query is that right?

Comment: opening bal= 5000, total_income =8000, total_exp =3500 and closing_bal =9500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT council_name,
       first_value(opening_bal) OVER w AS opening_bal,
       sum(income) OVER w AS total_income,
       sum(expenditure) OVER w AS total_expenditure,
       last_value(closing_balance) OVER w AS closing_balance
FROM my_table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY council_name ORDER BY date_compiled
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING);
```

This does the summing over the entire period in your table. You could add a `WHERE` clause to select a range of `date_compiled`, if so desired.

Comment: can i use the council_name on the where clause because there are many councils in the database

Comment: i tried and is not working.. it say the w does not exist

Comment: The window definition was missing a *frame clause* and the select list has to be `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicate rows (both fixed), but otherwise there should be no problem.

Comment: You can add a `WHERE` clause after the `FROM my_table` clause to select a limited number of councils. The query should return only a single row per council.